# Python: Clustering Search Keywords

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, cluster-analysis

I have a lot of "Search Keywords" for every product in the dataset. I try to cluster products according to their "Search Keywords".

What I'm looking to do is cluster these keywords into clusters of "similar meaning", and create a hierarchy of the clusters (structured in order of summed total number of searches per cluster).

An example cluster - "women's clothing" - would ideally contain keywords along these lines: women's clothing, 1000 ladies wear, 300 women's clothes, 50 ladies' clothing, 6 women wear, 2.

I'm a beginner in NLP. Do you have any suggestions of NLP techniques for this task? Any help will be highly appreciated :-)

Comment: hey @DataCat have you came up with a solution for your problem? would appreciate sharing your code here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use some pretrained word vectors,[fastText](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html) for example, so you don't have to worry with training and training data. What you would need to do:

- Preproces your labels: Tokenize your labels: `women's clothing` -> `["women's", "clothing"]`. [see here](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html)
- Lemmatize: `["women's", "clothing"]` -> `["woman", "clothing"]` [see here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html?highlight=lemmatizer)
- Calculate vector for each word: `vec1 = model.get_word_vector("woman")`
- Average all the vectors for a given Label: `avg= (vec1 + vec2)/2`
  These average vectors should represent your label. The average vectors of  `woman` and `clothing` should be in the same region as the average of `woman` and `wear`. on the other hand the average vector of `man` and `clothing` should be in a different region in the vector space, so your preferred [clustering algorithm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) shall catch it.